# Disable submit button if value less than specified

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable the submit button if the form total is less than $200.
I've hacked together some code but can't get it to work.

(total1) comes from another script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function () {      
      if ($('total1').val() > 200)
          $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
      else
          $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");      
      }
</script>

<form method="post" action="order.php">
Order total = $<input style="border: 0px solid #000000;" size="3" type="text" id="total1" readonly />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled title="Order is below $200 minimum.">
```

Comment: That function is just an anonymous function, and is not even called. Looks like you should read up on some basics of JavaScript first of all.

Comment: Try switching your attribute selection script to echo the value of $('total1') or something like that. $('total1') doesn't seem like a valid selector. If you set that as a variable somewhere else, it would look like `total1.val()`.

Comment: Why is input field readonly ?

Comment: just an enlightment, use .prop('disabled', true) , attr('disabled', 'disabled') is deprecheted also use true and false when needed, also -> i think it will solve your issue, if it does, tell me so ill open answer and you check it :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have an anonymous function that will never be called in that way.

If you want it to be called, you need to use it on some other input event "onchange", for example.
Look, [I've made a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TqM43/) using a setInterval to show you how it works:

```
setInterval(function () {
    if ($('#total1').val() >= 200)
        $(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    else
        $(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}, 1);

setInterval(function () {
    var vl = parseInt($("#total1").val());
    $("#total1").val(vl + 50);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Better keep it as disbaled and enable it when total is more than 200

Assuming total input box is not readonly. 
**Using JQuery**

```
<input style="border: 0px solid #000000;" size="3" type="text" id="total1" readonly />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled title="..." id="myButton"> 
// I have added id as myButton
<script>
$('#total1').change(function() {  // When value of total one is changed
  if ($('#total1').val() > 200)
          $("#myButton").removeAttr("disabled");
  else
          $("#myButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");      
  }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {    //Name the function  
      if ($('total1').val() > 200)
          $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
      else
          $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");      
      }
</script>

<form method="post" action="order.php" oninput="validate()"> <!-- Call validate form modification -->
    Order total = $<input style="border: 0px solid #000000;" size="3" type="text" id="total1" readonly />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled title="Order is below $200 minimum."/>
```